# Cannot clear blank space in email input

Tags: javascript

It seems that an `input` with `type="email"` cannot be cleared using `.value=""` if it contains only blank spaces in Chrome and Opera. Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: Replicated issue - http://jsfiddle.net/f1tq3svz/